# I need to obtain the key string from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, request

I have this JSON in a request for an laravel API:

```
{
  "questionary": {

    "directLeader": {
      "answer": "ALWAYS",
      "comments": "asdf"
    }
  },
  "id": 14 
}
```

I need to obtain the string "directLeader" 'cause this key changes in the request and I used that as a reference for a query update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To convert json to array:

$array = json_decode($json, true);

- To get the first key inside associative array:

$firstKey = array_key_first($array['questionary']);

**$firstKey** will contain your dynamic key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `json_decode()` the json you have like so

```
$json = '{
  "questionary": {

    "directLeader": {
      "answer": "ALWAYS",
      "comments": "asdf"
    }
  },
  "id": 14 
}';

$encoded_json = json_decode($json, true);

dd($encoded_json['questionary']['directLeader']);
```

**Note**
the `true` in `json_decode()` will convert the object to array, without `true` it will an object